# How to decrease space above shaded parbox in Lyx?

Tags: lyx

I'm using default settings in Lyx for document class etc., and use several small shaded boxes (via Insert -> Box -> Shaded Background). How do I decrease the amount of vertical space above and below these boxes? It is much more than for a Simple Frame box. Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have created two accounts (the one that created this question and http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39526/des) You can have them merged by following the instructions at http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 1):

You can control the space above and below a box individually by inserting this TeX code

```
\vspace{-0.2cm}
```

or whatever distance you like better.

Comment: Great, that works. Is there a way to re-define \begin{shaded} or \parbox so that it always includes a `\vspace{-0.5cm}%` before the normal TeX code?